# Printf and fstream operator << displaying different values. Why?

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

I'm trying to get the values of `x` and `y` coordinates of two eyes. I detect it using opencv XML file, and in the console 2 different `x` values appear from `printf()` while the text file I save  with `operator<<` displays 1 value. Why is this so?

```
printf("X = %o,Y = %o\n", eyes[j].x, eyes[j].y);

ofstream coordinates;
coordinates.open("C:/Users/dougl/Desktop/Coordinates.txt");
coordinates << "X = " << eyes[j].x << "\n" << "Y = " << eyes[j].y;
```

[image]

Comment: Why your using the %o ? Are expecting the octal number printing?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::oct;
using std::hex;

int main()
{
  long int pos_value =  12345678;  

  cout << "The decimal value 12345678 is printed out as" << endl;

  cout << "octal:       " << oct << pos_value << endl;
  cout << "hexadecimal: " << hex << pos_value << endl << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Printf showing the Unsigned Octal number for integer using: %o format.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/format-specifiers-in-c/amp/

Stream operator<< overload work as per the data type of the value passed.
So, to print octal value you need to formatting (std::oct) :

```
cout << "octal:       " << oct << pos_value << endl;
```

Reference:http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/c241man/node83.html

Answer (score 0):

You are telling `printf()` to output the integers in **octal** form, whereas `operator<<` outputs the integers in **decimal** form by default.

To make the two outputs match, you need to either:

- change `%o` to `%d` or `%u`, depending on whether the `x` and `y` values are signed or unsigned, respectively.
- use the [`std::oct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) I/O manipulator with `operator<<`.